# Plug-in to create comment layer

Tags: plugin-system, comments

Is there any plug-in where you can write text without being in insert mode but it’s not being written to the actual file? If you enter insert mode, all that comment text disappears. It should be in a different color, like light yellow, to indicate it’s just some temporary writing.

If there is no plug-in, how would you make this?

Thank you

Comment: Generally what people do (I think) is to open a scratch or notes buffer (`:help scratch-buffer`)

Comment: You can't type text "without being in insert mode". I don't think what you are trying to do exists. It might be possible but not trivial: You could create a comment which takes note of where you are in the undo list [`:h :undolist`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/undo.txt.html#%3Aundolist) and would revert to this point when you run a command again. But there would probably be some painful edge cases. I would advise following Ben's advice and simply take your notes in a temporary buffer.

Comment: Another solution would be to insert your comments with a marker (like `//`), have a script which takes a file as input and returns the same file with the marked text remove and run this script with [`:h 'formatprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatprg%27) when you save your file.

Comment: @statox Just theoretically, would it take to remove all commands in normal mode and instead make the keyboard send input to be display on-screen, and when you do Ctrl-i that text is lost and normal Vim insert mode begins?

Comment: Maybe it would be possible in vimscript but it would be super hacky, have tons of edge cases and overall I don't think it would be worth the work. The other alternative is to implement that in the source code of vim or neovim, but at this point that would be a whole fork which would take a lot of work. I know I tend to mention that a lot on this site but I think your question might be another instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/288754): What are you actually trying to achieve? What is the workflow you want to fix?